# remove all words containing backslash

Tags: sed

ive been tring sooooo many different variations to get this right.

i am simply looking to use sed to remove all words beginning with or containing a backslash.

so string

```
another test \/ \u7896 \n test ha\ppy
```

would become

```
another test test
```

i've tried soo many different options, but it doesnt seem to want to work. Does anybody have an idea how to do this?

and before everyone starts giving me minus 1 for this question, believe me, i have tried to find the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ echo "another test \/ \u7896 \n test ha\ppy" | sed -r 's/\S*\\\S*//g' | tr -s '[:blank:]'
another test test
```

Comment: You can add a `| tr -s ' '` to delete multiple spaces.

Comment: @fedorqui Right, I was already adding it when noticed your comment =). Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `str.split` and a `list comprehension`:

```
>>> strs = "another test \/ \u7896 \n test ha\ppy"
>>> [x for x in strs.split() if '\\' not in x]
['another', 'test', 'test']

# use str.join to join the list
>>> ' ' .join([x for x in strs.split() if '\\' not in x])
'another test test'
```

Comment: im actually looking for a sed command to do this, since its part of the os.command optiom, and my query is very long. features a few sed's and grep's

Comment: @RHK-S8 so what is that [tag:python] doing in your question?

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\s*\S*\\\S*//g' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string = "another test \/ \u7896 \n test ha\ppy"            
string_no_slashes = " ".join([x for x in string.split() if "\\" not in x])
```